# How to generate a float or double list using range()?

Tags: python, list, syntax, range

```
t = range(10, 20, 1)
```

this generates a list of integer elements.

but I want to generate a list of float (double) elements with the same values like

```
t = range(10.0, 20.0, 1.0)
```

this doesn't work.

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
```

Comment: `map(float, range(10, 20))` — see [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do it with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). As a workaround, you may use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to type-cast the values to `float` as:

```
>>> map(float, range(10, 20, 1))
[10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can type cast `int` to `float`.

```
>>> [float(x) for x in range(10,20,1)]
[10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[i*1.0 for i in range(10, 20, 1)]
```